# Search in Two level nested entities

Tags: website-design, search

I'm working on a search page in a website for two nested entities like class and student.
the user can searches for **specific students** like students that has these two sets of properties:

```
gender=male
Height=short
```

The user can also add other criteria and searches for **specific classes** that have some students with this properties:

```
gender=female
Height=long
```

and

```
gender=male
Weight<50
```

[image: sample screenshot]

So the question is:
Have I over complicated the search with this combination?

Is there any other design for support the combination of search in this two level nested entities?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a use case to either search classes with students matching some criteria AND students with the these criteria it does not seem to be over complicated. The question is how to point the user to the two different types of search.

The best way to do so, is not to let the user handle this. What you could do is search both (students and classes with students) and provide to result sets. It depends on the screen space you have how to handle these. You could use tabs, an maybe even provide a amount of results in the tab title. Something like this:

Students matching your search (25)   |   Classes with students matching your search (4)

This way the user will not have to decide which search to perform instead the user can concentrate on the search.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think sowing the aggregated result of Schools after declaring multiple students types is very complicated. I've update the Q and add an image of my UI scratch.